# "ERROR" message keeps appearing when I try to use query formula

Tags: google-sheets

I used semicolon, but it shows "ERROR"
(I named my range info) The formula that I used is:

```
=query(info;"Select *";1)
```

and when I clicked enter, it just appears "ERROR"

Could you please help me

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Is ```info``` a [named range](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) ?. I just tried with a named range that I called info and it worked.